# Need to setup a RMTP stream from our server with multicast

Tags: nginx, streaming, live-streaming, iptv

I have a client with a 1-2 thousand viewer audience, with everyday streams, same concurrent number of viewers.

Ive got a server set up for their website etc, but am in the process of figuring out the best way to stream with OBS onto that server, and than re-distribute that stream to clients (as an embed on the website).

Now from the calculations i did, running that kind of concurrent viewers is very problematic, as it forces you into a 10gbit link - which is very expensive, and i would ideally like to fit within 1-2gbps, if possible.

A friend of mine recommended to look into "Multicast" which supossedly uses MUCH less bandwith than regular live streaming options. Is multicast doable? Ive had a NGINX live stream set up on my server by a friend before, but never looked into the config and if multicast is supported within that. Are there any other options? What would you recommend?

Also, the service of that live stream isnt a high profit / organisation type of deal, so any pre-made services just dont make sense, as it would easily cost 40+ dollars per stream, which is just too much for my client.

Thank you for any help!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Multicast, P2P is more practical solution on Internet, to save money not bandwidth.

Especially for H5 browser, it's possible to use `WebRTC DataChannel` to transport P2P data.

But Multicast does not work on internet routers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, does this "reduce" the required bandwith or keep it at 8gbps+ ? Thats the calculations i have done, and why i was interested in multicast.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast works by sending a single stream across the network to edge points where clients can 'join' the multicast to get an individual stream for them.

It requires that the network supports multicast protocols and the edges align with your users.

It is typically used when an operator has their own IP network for service like IPTV, rather than for services over the internet.

For your scenario, you would usually use an organ server and a CDN - this will usually reduce the load on your own server as the video will be cached on the network and multiple user can access the same 'chunks' of the video.

You can see and AWS example for on demand video here - other vendor and cloud providers have solutions too so this is just an example:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tutorial-s3-cloudfront-route53-video-streaming.html

You can find more complex On Demand and Live tutorial also but they are likley more that you need: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

Exploring P2P may be an option also as Winton suggests - some CDN may also leverage P2P technology internally.